# How to make Drupal use php 5.6 instead of php 7.1.7 (default php version of Sierra)

Tags: php, macos, drupal

macOs High Sierra comes with php 7 by default. I want to run a Drupal 6 website on php 5.6. I have already installed php 5.6.

Running php -v gives

> PHP 5.6.33 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2018 11:14:18) Copyright (c) 1997-2016
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

But when I print phpinfo() in drupal website, it shows **PHP Version 7.1.7** as version.

How can I make drupal use php 5.6 ?

Comment: Not a solution put other proposal - why don't you use VM machine? With vagrant you can have you environment ready in minutes, without any configuration on your side. And you can choose env closer to production one - you site eventually won't run on Mac, but on some linux box.

Comment: The command line seems to use its own version of PHP. I'd follow the rabbit trail of 'what is your server (apache, nginx, etc) -> search for said servers php update docs.' If you're using something like cPanel or Plesk for managing the site's environment, I know the latter for sure has an option to choose a PHP version per domain... I imagine cPanel does too.